# PHP Separate URL String

Tags: php, string, parsing

I have a really simple question that I couldn't solve using online help...

Well I have an URL, eg. "www.google.com/hello/xxxxxxxx"

What I'm trying to do is get that xxxxxxx and print it. I have already gathered the URL of the page I want to split with a SQL statement, and it is now stored in the $row['url'].
I have tried to get it it split when it reaches an "/"

This is my code right now:

```
$url = preg_split("[/.-]", $row['url']);
print_r($url);
```

But it doesn't work? Right now it doesn't even print anything... and I don't know what else to try!

Comment: Why? http://php.net/parse_url already does all this for you You're using preg_split wrong - there's no delimiters. e.g. `'/[\/.-]/`

Comment: @MarcB Yes I know but I will need this for different stuff that doesn't involved URLs forcedly and I would like to use it as reference. What should I use instead of preg_split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
$url = "www.google.com/hello/xxxxxxxx" ;

echo substr( strrchr( $url, '/' ), 1 );
```

Output: xxxxxxxx

Comment: You are most welcome. You may check answer from @BenM as well. It will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [`end()`](https://www.php.net/end) with [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/explode):

```
echo end(explode('/', $row['url']));
```

Output is: `xxxxxxxx`.